# GtkListStore - how to center text?

Tags: c, gtk

I have included a brief snippet of code. I'm making a Tree View with 5 columns. I have pasted the last column with the for loop that generates the data to be stored in the GtkListStore. I can center the columns of the Tree View easily. I have looked online to find out how to center the text in the GtkListStore and I am not finding a solution. I have looked through the documentation:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkListStore.html

On the last link, I do not see an alignment property. Is there a way to align all of the objects through the GtkTreeModel? I haven't found any online examples using the GtkListStore and aligning text... really appreciate the help!

```
// Append Table Velocity column
column = gtk_tree_view_column_new();
gtk_tree_view_column_set_title(column, "Pressure");
gtk_tree_view_column_set_min_width(column, 60);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_alignment(column, 0.5); // 0.0 left, 0.5 center, 1.0 right
// Code Above center's the column title in the Tree View

renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
g_object_set( G_OBJECT( renderer ), "xalign", 0.5 );    // xalign, 0.5
// Code above doesn't change alignment..

gtk_tree_view_column_pack_start(column, renderer, FALSE);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_attributes(column, renderer, "text", 4, NULL);
gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), column);

// List Store
liststore = gtk_list_store_new(5, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

int i;
for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
// Append test data
gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &iter, 0, i, 1, "5", 2, "0.2", 3, "123", 4, "0.5", -1);
// How do I center the text stored in the GtkListStore?
}

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a convenient function called gtk_tree_view_column_with_attributes(). Using this function and two more lines of code I can conveniently center the text in the header and the list store.

```
// Append Pressure column
column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Pressure", renderer, "text", 4, NULL);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_alignment(column, 0.5);
gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), column);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `g_object_set (renderer, "xalign", 0.5, NULL);` with the NULL at the end, g_object_set needs a sentinel. Actually leaving out the sentinel should have given you at least a compiler warning, or did you leave it out deliberately or by mistake?

Comment: I added the `g_object_set (renderer, "xalign", 0.5, NULL);` immediately after the `renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();` and the table hasn't changed. The columns are aligned by the following: `gtk_tree_view_column_set_alignment(column, 0.5);` I did get a compiler warning but even with the NULL the table still looks the same.

Comment: I have to admit that I find this rather odd, since I use code similar to yours (I use a treeview, but it shouldn't make a difference), and if I insert `g_object_set (renderer, "xalign", 0.5, NULL);` everything works as expected. Maybe you could post your exact version of GTK (3.4, 2.16...), your distribution or whether you are using it with Windows and the Gtk theme you are using.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I'm using GTK+ 2.24.10 on Windows. Theme name: "MS-Windows" I may compile the example under linux and see if the appearance changes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A gtk4 help/update can be useful now a day.

GtkColumnView and GListStore should be used over all the legacy stuff.

Inside the setup_cb, add
`gtk_widget_set_halign(label, GTK_ALIGN_START);`